# Appending an array with multiple arrays in google script

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I have an array where I send a set of values after an operation on a spreadsheet followed by taking the average.
Now I want to return each row also along with the above data.

I thought of using two-dimensional arrays.
But I have less clarity in implementing this.

---

```
for (var i = 0; i < spreadsheetRows.length; i++)
{
    //operations done and variables updated
    variable1=
    variable2=

    variablen=
}

var sendArray = [];

sendArray.push(variable1);
sendArray.push(variable2);
sendArray.push(variable3);
sendArray.push(variable4);
return sendArray;
```

---

*Now i want to send the array **rowFirst & rowSecond** also*

```
for (var i = 0; i < spreadsheetRows.length; i++)
{
    //first row of spreadsheet
    rowFirst=[];  //data of first row
    rowSecond=[]; //data of second row

    //operations done and variables updated
    variable1=
    variable2=

    variablen=

}
    var sendArray = [];
    sendArray.push(variable1);
    sendArray.push(variable2);
    sendArray.push(variable3);
    sendArray.push(variable4);

    sendArray.push(rowFirst); // stuck here <---
    sendArray.push(rowSecond);// stuck here <----
    return sendArray;
```

How to send the array with these two data( ie rowFirst and rowSecond) . Please guide me.

## Output Expected

```
sendArray=[
    var1,
    var2, 
    var3,
    varn,
    rowFirst=[num1, num2, num3,...numn]
    rowSeocnd=[num1, num2, num3,...numn]
]
```

Comment: So, you want to add two empty arrays, `rowFirst` and `rowSecond` to the `sendArray`?

Comment: @BrianBennett - this is what i am looking for - `sendArray=[
var1,
var2, 
var3,
varn,
rowFirst=[num1, num2, num3,...numn],
rowSeocnd=[num1, num2, num3,...numn]
]`

Comment: i just want to pass these data to the function. please suggest any possible way

Answer (score 1):

To answer your immediate question, you can push an array into another array by using square brackets in `push`.

```
sendArray.push([rowFirst]);
sendArray.push([rowSecond]);
```

Based on your comment, you may want to use an Object, not an Array ([here's a helpful article on the differences](https://www.metaltoad.com/blog/javascript-understanding-objects-vs-arrays-and-when-use-them-part-1)). So, think through why you'd want four variables not associated with anything. Can those be grouped or keyed somehow? There are a number of ways to do this and a simple method is to use dot notation to pair a variable or a data set to an object key.

```
// declare the object and each array
var sendObject = {}

// from your code...
for (var i = 0; i < spreadsheetRows.length; i++)
{
    //operations done and variables updated
    variable1=
    variable2=

    var rowFirst = [variable1, variable2, ...]
}

// Create the key in the Object and assign the array
sendObject.rowFirst = rowFirst;

The output would be:

sendObject = {
  "rowFirst": [variable1, variable2, ...]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. @Brian Bennett
And when i return in a function
how can i separate the values.
`function myFunc(){
.
.
.
 return sendObject;
}

var CallerObj = myFunc();
CallerObj.rowFirst=?
`

Comment: You can open the object using dot notation and loop through arrays. So, `for(var i=0; i<CallerObj.rowFirst.length; i++) { // do stuff... }` Take a look at the article I linked. It'll help.

Comment: I tried  but getting - `Uncaught Error: The script completed but the returned value is not a supported return type`

Comment: You may need to wrap it in `JSON.stringify()` and open with `JSON.parse()`.